# Evaluation of two specific definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, integration-by-parts, trigonometric-integrals

These two definite integrals come from the brachistochrone problem, where $g$ denotes gravitational acceleration (9.81 $m/s^2$) and $C$ is a constant function. How am I supposed to solve them? I've tried a trigonometric substitution in the first one, but haven't gone too far.

1) $\mathcal{I}_1 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \int_0^1 \sqrt\frac{4x^2 + 1}{x^2 + C} dx$

2) $\mathcal{I}_2 = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}} \int_0^1 \sqrt\frac{4x + 1}{4x(\sqrt{x} + C)} dx$

Comment: Wolfram gives evaluation of the first integral (excluding the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}$) as $$-i\cdot E\left(i\sinh^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\Bigr)\bigg\vert 4C\right)$$ Can't get it to spit out anything nice for the second integral though.